# start workflow automatically when an items changed in one column sharepoint 2010?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

i have list **ABC** containing 3 columns

**Column Name :** Name
**Type :**    single line of text

**Data :** I-Touch

**Column Name :** Address
**Type :**    multiple line of text

**Data :** xyz

**Column Name :** Age
**Type :**    Choice (menu to choose from)

**Data :**    Choice #1
              Choice #2
              Choice #3

my start option is : **start workflow automatically when an items changed**

currently m trying to run workflow only when the data in column with name **Age** is changed.
i dont want to create new column to save previous Age value.

i dont want to run the workflow when data in column with name **Name** & **Address** is changes.

is there any trick?

Comment: No there is no trick, you must do what you don't want to do, store the previous value in a hidden column and evaluate against that.